# Drupal 8 me elimina el espacio entre el header y el contenido cuando se encuentra en la pestaña de administración

Tags: headers, drupal8

Hola comunidad tengo este problema:
Drupal 8 me elimina el espacio existente entre el header y el contenido cuando esta en la pestaña de adminstracion en la seccion de Atajos y Usuario. Cuando cambio de pestaña de administracion el problema desaparece.

[image: Con el problema]

[image: despues del problema]

Comment: Por favor, agrega más detalles a tu pregunta: lee [ask].

Comment: La toolbar de Drupal tiene un css que seguramente entre en conflicto con el estilo de tu plantilla. Deberás identificar que estilos son para poder aplicar correcciones a tu css